# Node.js server generated automatically doesn't start (Swagger/OpenAPI)

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I have generated a nodejs-server by Swagger Editor, but when I run "npm start" the server doesn't start and return no error.

First time I've run "npm start" all dependencies has been installed, but "node index.js" doesn't start the server.

Second time I've tried "npm start":

```sh
dev01@dev01:~/nodejs-server$ npm start

> back-end-rota-exata@1.0.0 prestart /home/dev01/nodejs-server
> npm install


> back-end-rota-exata@1.0.0 start /home/dev01/nodejs-server
> node index.js

dev01@dev01:~/nodejs-server$
```

Then I've tried just "node index.js" too:

```sh
dev01@dev01:~/nodejs-server$ node index
dev01@dev01:~/nodejs-server$
```

And nothing happens...

This is the code from "index.js" generated automatically by Swagger Editor:

```js
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    http = require('http');

var app = require('connect')();
var oas3Tools = require('oas3-tools');
var jsyaml = require('js-yaml');
var serverPort = 8080;

// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
  swaggerUi: path.join(__dirname, '/swagger.json'),
  controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
  useStubs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
};

// The Swagger document (require it, build it programmatically, fetch it from a URL, ...)
var spec = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'api/swagger.yaml'), 'utf8');
var swaggerDoc = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);

// Initialize the Swagger middleware
oas3Tools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, function (middleware) {

  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  // Validate Swagger requests
  app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator());

  // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(options));

  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

  // Start the server
  http.createServer(app).listen(serverPort, function () {
    console.log('Your server is listening on port %d (http://localhost:%d)', serverPort, serverPort);
    console.log('Swagger-ui is available on http://localhost:%d/docs', serverPort);
  });

});
```

Note: I did not modified any lines.

Comment: The server generated code should not be an issue. If the `swagger.yaml` file was badly configured or missing an error should have popped up. This does not seem like a swagger problem. Can you run other node.js applications?

Comment: Yes, I can run other node.js applications, this is the first time I have a problem like that. 
I've already run an application like that before, the difference is that I used swagger 2.0, this time I'm using openapi 3.0.0

Comment: You should add an error handler to your http-server instance to find the cause. Example: `http.createServer(function(req, res) {}).listen(3000).on('error', console.log);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, what I did was change in the definition of `swagger.yaml` from `openapi: 3.0.0` to `openapi: 3.0.1`, and the server worked.